# Targeting Trident 6 (MSHTML 10) for IE 10

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, dom, mshtml

I am working on an app that needs to access IE and manipulate HTML5. I have worked with MSHTML versions before but could not find information on how to reference and redistribute MSHTML 10. The version installed on Windows 7 with VS 2010 and IE 10 is MSHTML 7.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** As Vitor Canova suggested, I found mshtml.dll version 10.0.9200.16576 in System32 and SysWOW64 folders but it appears to be a native DLL and there are no primary interop assemblies installed that show up filtered in the references dialog. I could probably reference it as a COM dll but wanted to know if a PIA officially exists and what the redistribution conditions are.

Comment: With my Windows 7 with VS 2010 and IE 10 I have mshtml.dll version 10.0.9200.16576 in System32 and SysWOW64 folder.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same but from a quick inspection, it is a native DLL and there are no primary interop assemblies installed that show up filtered in the references dialog. I could probably reference it as a COM dll but wanted to know if a PIA officially exists and what the redistribution conditions are.

Comment: Got it. Added to a project and it points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Common\Microsoft.mshtml.dll`.

Comment: Maybe it can be available in the new version o [Tools for Office](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2013/03/06/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2012-now-available.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0).

Comment: Not sure. The one you mention under VS 10 is MSHTML 7.

Comment: Just verified with someone else. Visual Studio 2012 and Office 2013 still has the same version.